# Pass a mixture of differend enums types in delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, enums

I need to write a procedure where can pass different enum selections.

```
type
  TEnumOne = (eOneFlagOne, eOneFlagTwo);
  TEnumTwo = (eTwoFlagOne, eTwoFlagTwo);
```

The method should take different enums:

```
Process([eOneFlagOne, eTwoFlagTwo]);
```

I'm trying to implement it like this:

```
// does not work!
procedure Process(const Enums: array of Variant);
var aValue; Variant
begin
  for aValue in Enums do
  begin
    // of course, can't work...
    if aValue is TEnumOne then
  end; 
end;
```

So, is there a type instead of Variant, I can choose? Or is the a different approach, I dont' see?

Comment: Just out of memory, if I'm not mistaken, you can convert an enum to/from an integer, for example, `I:= Integer(eOneFlagOne);` and `F:= TEnumOne(I);` and in that case, if `eOneFlagOne = 0` then `eTwoFlagOne = 0` too. Unless you want more of a unique ID to go with it, like 0,1/2,3 instead of 0,1/0,1, and in that case, I don't know.

Comment: Or, as an alternative, use constants instead, for example, `const E_ONE_FLAG_ONE = 0; E_ONE_FLAG_TWO = 1; E_TWO_FLAG_ONE = 2; E_TWO_FLAG_TWO = 3;` etc. and use those instead of enums.

Comment: By the way, I'm sure RRUZ is asking for the version probably because newer versions such as XE2 might offer easier ways of doing this...

Comment: Your design sounds like it is flawed. Rather than fighting the language, I would be reconsidering the design. For what it's worth, in order to write something like if aValue is TEnumOne you obviously need to be using classes rather than enums. Those classes could hold enums.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE. The problem is, the enums are autogenerated by remobjects as a interface. So I can't change the definition of the enums.

Comment: Please add a mention in your question that these type definitions are automatically created by remobjects and that you cannot change how it is defined.

Answer (score 10):

Meet the beauty of pascal.

Here's a working example of what you're probably trying to do:

```
program Project34; {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TEnum=(eOneFlagOne,eOneFlagTwo,eTwoFlagOne,eTwoFlagTwo);
  TEnumSet=set of TEnum;

const
  cEnumOne=[eOneFlagOne,eOneFlagTwo];
  cEnumTwo=[eTwoFlagOne,eTwoFlagTwo];

procedure Process(const Enums: TEnumSEt);
var e:TEnum;
begin
  for e in Enums do
    WriteLn(ord(e));
end;

begin
  Process([eOneFlagOne, eTwoFlagTwo]);
  Process(cEnumOne);
  Process(cEnumTwo);
end.
```

Note that you can also declare the constants like this. Maybe that's clearer:

```
const
  cEnumOne:TEnumSet=[eOneFlagOne,eOneFlagTwo];
  cEnumTwo:TEnumSet=[eTwoFlagOne,eTwoFlagTwo];
```

Comment: To complete this you would want TEnumOne = eOneFlagOne..eOneFlagTwo etc

Comment: Sadly, I cannot change or extend the type definition of the enmus. I also cannot build a set.

Comment: @FrancoisZbinden If you cannot change the type definition of the enums, and if you cannot build a set, you should change the Process-function, so that it takes two parameters, Process(EnumOneArray: Array of TEnumOne; EnumTwoArray: Array of TEnumTwo), and then check for conditions in both arrays.

Answer (score 4):

To be blunt, when you start trying to bend your language like this, it usually means that your approach is probably wrong. (not always, but usually) I'd be interested to hear what problem you are trying to solve, as maybe there is a better design option.

With what little we know about your problem, I would suggest that either you create 2 functions with the different signatures. 

Or
if the required logic branch is similar enough to each other, then you could create a Generic method (assuming Delphi 2009 or higher) using the enum type as your generic parm.

```
...
procedure Process<T>(const enumParam : T) // Add a generic constraint here as well
begin
...
end;
```

Seems likely to me however, that the 2 different methods would be the likely best option (or something else entirely)

Answer (score 1):

RRUZ deleted his answer, here is a reworked version with type safety.
RTTI is used to identify the different enum constants.

```
function EnumToString(const TypeInfo : pTypeInfo; Ix : Integer) : string;
begin
  Result := GetEnumName(TypeInfo, ix); 
end;

procedure Process( const Args : array of string);
var
  LIndex,ix : integer;
  EnumOne : TEnumOne;
  EnumTwo : TEnumTwo;
begin
  for LIndex := 0 to High(Args) do begin
    ix := GetEnumValue( TypeInfo(TEnumOne), Args[LIndex]);
    if (ix <> -1) then
    begin
      EnumOne := TEnumOne( ix); 
      // do something with EnumOne
      ...
      continue;
    end;

    ix := GetEnumValue( TypeInfo(TEnumTwo), Args[LIndex]);
    if (ix <> -1) then
    begin
      EnumTwo := TEnumTwo( ix); 
      // do something with EnumTwo
      ...
      continue;
    end; 
    ... 
    etc

  end;        
end;

Process( [EnumToString(TypeInfo(TEnumOne),Ord(TEnumOne.eOneFlagOne)),
          EnumToString(TypeInfo(TEnumTwo),Ord(TEnumTwo.eTwoFlagTwo))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to keep it as just one enum:

```
TEnum = (eOneFlagOne, eOneFlagTwo, eTwoFlagOne, eTwoFlagTwo);
```

The Process function would then look like this:

```
procedure Process(Enums: Array of TEnum);
var 
  aValue: TEnum;
begin
  for aValue in Enums do
  begin
    if aValue in [eOneFlagOne, eOneFlagTwo] then
      // Handle the eOne enums
    else if aValue in [eTwoFlagOne, eTwoFlagTwo] then
      // Handle the eTwo enums
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: This merely repeats Wouter's answer. Unless you add something novel it's just clutter

Comment: Using a set (like Wouter propose) is more native and efficient to the pascal language, than such an open parameter array.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I agree. However, it does not matter much in practical terms. It will only matter if the function is part of some core loop that needs to be highly optimized.