# Is it possible to pass enumeration type as parameter and reuse this type in other functions?

Tags: delphi

What I want to achieve is just like the dummy code:

```
type
  CommandSetOne = (Command1, Command2, Command3);
  CommandSetTwo = (Command4, Command5, Command6);

  TRobot = class
    procedure RegisterCommands(anyEnumerationType : TRttiEnumerationType);
    procedure ExecuteCommands(anEnumeration : theEnumerationType);
  end;
```

Which I may have multiple set of command, and any command in command set is replaceable.

TRobot has a procedure can take a enumeration type as parameter, and he will save this type, use this type for the ExecuteCommands procedure.

About passing any enumeration type as parameter, I found out a way to do that is to use TRttiEnumerationType, in the call side it should looks like:

```
var
  rttiContext : TRttiContext;
  typeref : TRttiType;
  RobotA : TRobot;
begin
  rttiContext := TRttiContext.Create();
  RobotA := TRobot.Create();
  RobotA.RegisterCommands(rttiContext.GetType(TypeInfo(CommandSetOne)));
end;
```

but I got stuck on passing a Command like Command1. I have tried Variant for theEnumerationType but seems I can not pass Command1 to this.

I know if I use something like TStringList for this is a much easier way to do what I want, but I would like to have a check by delphi at complies time in case I mistype some command(use TstringList I can add code to check at runtime)

so the real problem is:

1. which type should I use for theEnumerationType?
2. if it's not possible to to this, any other solution to use Enumeration?
3. or any solution can provide a complies time check as well as a flexible structure?

EDIT:

thanks for David suggested, I should use both Rtti things, so to make it clear, I add the implementation for RegisterCommands

```
implementation
  procedure TRobot.RegisterCommands(anyEnumerationType : TRttiEnumerationType);
    begin
    theEnumerationType := anyEnumerationType;
    end;
  procedure TRobot.ExecuteCommands (anyEnumerationValueoftheType : ???);
    begin
    //do something with the command
    end;
```

so what should fit for any enumeration value for the type?

for example, if I use **CommandSetOne** in RegisterCommands,
how can delphi accept **Command1** or **Command2** or **Command3**?

more specifically, can delphi limit the room only for **Command1** or **Command2** or **Command3**? means if I put **Command4** it give me an compile error?

Comment: Why are you using RTTI at all? This sounds like a job for Generics instead.

Comment: What is `theEnumerationType`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan theEnumerationType is either CommandSetOne or CommandSetTwo or any Enumeration type I Register to Trobot

Comment: @RemyLebeau it's kind of Generics, because the type send to RegisterCommands may be changed

Comment: @Mengchao But `ExecuteCommands` cannot ever compile.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's actually the first question, I wonder the type I should put here.

Comment: Generics are surely the answer here. For both functions. You don't want the calling code to have to frab around with RTTI. Btw, you can remove the `rttiContext := TRttiContext.Create();` line which serves no purpose at all.

Comment: You could check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110704/pass-a-mixture-of-differend-enums-types-in-delphi

Comment: Regarding your edit that's the exact opposite of what I suggested

Comment: I recall in a skill sprint being told that generics do not deal with enums well.  Actually i found that within limits they handle them pretty well. But I struggle trying to understand what you are trying to achieve. How is ExecuteCommands meant to work? If you can explain that I may have some ideas.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hmmm... what is the opposite to enumeration?

Comment: @Dsm The ExecuteCommands does nothing special, actually he will just run an event to let call side decide what thing to do. as I said I can use stringlist to do this, which it's element is string, but that provide no type check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself wanting to pass the type of something as a parameter the goto solution is generics.

We're going to abuse the fact that an enumeration is really an integer underneigh.
Let's assume you have the actual command encoded in the string representation of the enum label.
e.g.

```
TCommands = (Left, Right, Up, Down);

TRobot = class
private
  FRegisteredCommands: TDictionary<integer, string>;
public  
  procedure RegisterCommand<E: record>(Enum : E);
  procedure ExecuteCommand<E: record>(Enum : E);
end;

procedure TRobot.RegisterCommand<E: record>(Enum: E);
var
  Key: integer absolute Enum;  //typesafe, because of the if below.  
  Info: PTypeInfo;
begin
  if GetTypeKind(E) <> tkEnumeration then raise Exception.Create('Enum is not an enum');
  //Added type safety:
  if     not(TypeInfo(E) = TypeInfo(TRobotCommand1)) 
      or not(TypeInfo(E) = TypeInfo(TRobotCommend2)) then raise ....
  Info:= TypeInfo(Enum);
  FRegisteredCommands.Add(Key, GetEnumName(Info, Key));
end;
```

*[The compiler will **remove** all this `if` code if these checks are true and only generate the code if these checks are false, because `GetTypeKind` is a compiler intrinsic routine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30417597/650492) This means that it will take zero runtime to execute these checks*
Note that you can use the `if TypeInfo(E) = TypeInfo(TMyCommandSet)` compiler intrinsics trick to hardcode the command if crazy fast performance is your thing.

Note that on early Delphi's the `absolute` directive causes a compiler internal error (in Seattle it works 100% fine). In that case change the code like so:

```
procedure TRobot.RegisterCommand<E: record>(Enum: E);
var
  Key: integer;
  Info: PTypeInfo;
begin
  ....
  Key:= PInteger(@Enum)^;
  .....
```

If a given TRobot descendent only accepts a single type of command then I'd move the generic type to TRobot like so:

```
TBaseRobot<E: record> = class(TObject)
   constructor Create; virtual;
   procedure RegisterCommand(Enum: E);  //only implement once, see above.
   procedure ExecuteCommand(Enum: E); virtual; abstract; //implement in descendents.
....

constructor TBaseRobot<E>.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  if GetTypeKind(E) <> tkEnumeration then raise('error: details');  
end;

TRobotA = class(TBaseRobot<TMyEnum>)
  procedure ExecuteCommand(Enum: TMyEnum); override;
end;
....
```

**EDIT**
Instead of doing the check in the constructor, you can do it in a `class constructor`. The benefit of this is that any error will fire as soon as your app starts and not at some random time which may never happen in your testing.

Remove the constructor and replace it with a class constructor like so:

```
//You should never name a class constructor `create`. class constructor don't create anything, they init stuff.
class constructor TBaseRobot<E>.Init;  
begin
  if GetTypeKind(E) <> tkEnumeration then raise('error: details');  
end;
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I really appreciate the TypeInfo method. I will make an approach by a mixture of TypeInfo and Rtti

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @DavidHeffernan and @Johan, I make a mixture of the two approach, and it works perfectly. sadly I can still not perform a complies time check on that.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Typinfo, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TRobot = class
    private
      FPTypeInfo : PTypeInfo;
    public
      procedure RegisterCommands<E : record>;
      procedure ExecuteCommands<E : record>(anEnumeration : E);
  end;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
      RobotA : TRobot;
    end;

  CommandSetOne = (Command1, Command2, Command3);
  CommandSetTwo = (Command4, Command5, Command6);

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TRobot }

procedure TRobot.ExecuteCommands<E>(anEnumeration: E);
  begin
  if (TypeInfo(E) = FPTypeInfo) then
    begin
    showMessage('correct command type');
    end
  else
    begin
    raise Exception.Create('Enum type not correct');
    end;
  end;

procedure TRobot.RegisterCommands<E>;
  begin
  FPTypeInfo := TypeInfo(E);
  end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);      
  begin
  RobotA := TRobot.Create();
  RobotA.RegisterCommands<CommandSetOne>;
  end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  RobotA.ExecuteCommands(command1);
  end;

procedure TForm3.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  RobotA.ExecuteCommands(command4);
  end;

end.
```

Comment: I still think you have this all wrong. No need at all for the consumer of the class to do anything with rtti. This is poor design.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think that either I have to inform the TRobot the type or the robot need to search the rtti for some fixed name

Comment: You can do it the way Johan describes using generics

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's strange for just send one command to Register a commandset I think

Comment: Don't you find it odd that you convert from type info to rtti type and then back again. Just use a generic and obtain the type info. Remove the argument though on the register function.

Comment: I edited what I mean into your answer. Might not compile but you get my meaning.

Comment: thanks, that looks much better, just remove the TRttiContext it will compile